# Ajax Tooltips with data-id

Tags: jquery, ajax

I´m using qtip2 ajax-tooltips. This is the script (http://jsfiddle.net/craga89/L6yq3/):

```
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
$(document).ready(function()
{
 // MAKE SURE YOUR SELECTOR MATCHES SOMETHING IN YOUR HTML!!!
 $('a').each(function() {
     $(this).qtip({
        content: {
            text: 'Loading...',
            ajax: {
                url: 'http://qtip2.com/demos/data/owl',
                loading: false
            }
        },
        position: {
            viewport: $(window)
        },
        style: 'qtip-wiki'
     });
 });
 });
```

To use the script i need the link of the ajax file:

```
<a href='http://qtip2.com/demos/data/snowyowl'>Snowy Owl</a>
```

I want to call the ajax file without the link, but with the data-id attribute, so it looks like:

```
<a href="#" data-id="1">Snowy Owl</a>
```

How to make it?

To make it more clear, something like this code:

```
var urlFormat = "/content/web/tooltip/ajax/ajaxContent{0}.html";

            $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#products").qtip({
                    filter: "a",
                    content: {
                        url: "/content/web/tooltip/ajax/ajaxContent1.html"
                    },
                    width: 520,

                    position: "top",
                    requestStart: function(e) {
                        e.options.url = qtip.format(urlFormat, e.target.data("id"));
                    }
                });

                $("#products").find("a").click(false);
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are after is this:

```
// Create the tooltips only when document ready
 $(document).ready(function()
 {
     // MAKE SURE YOUR SELECTOR MATCHES SOMETHING IN YOUR HTML!!!
     $('a').each(function() {
         $(this).qtip({
            content: {
                text: 'Loading...',
                ajax: {
                    url: $(this).data('id'),
                    loading: false
                }
            },
            position: {
                viewport: $(window)
            },
            style: 'qtip-wiki'
         });
     });
 });
```

Note that I changed the url parameter from a fixed url to use the data-id attribute from the hovered link. `url: $(this).data('id'),`

It even seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/L6yq3/492/

**edit**
You could just build the url yourself then, and add the id in there somewhere. Something like this:
`url: 'http://path/to/ajax/script-' + $(this).data('id'),`

Or if you have a (php) script on the server you could add the id as a query variable and do the processing there. Something like this
`url: 'http://path/to/ajax/script.php?id=' + $(this).data('id'),`

Note that you could also use the actual `id`attribute, and not the `data-id` attribute by replacing `$(this).data('id')` by `$(this).attr('id')`

You get the idea?

Comment: Thanks so far. But i´m searching a solution where i have a folder where all my ajax files are inside. Now i want to call them just with  the ids.

Comment: Ok i´ve a folder with these ajax files, which are build like so: ajaxContent1.html, ajaxContent2.html .... So with your  first solution it´s the url: 'http://path/to/ajax/ajaxContent-' + $(this).data('id'). But the tooltip doesn´t find this script.